# htmlspecialchars + addslashes, makes any sense?

Tags: php, security, htmlspecialchars, addslashes

I'm trying to sanitize a string to be saved in a db.
First step I took was to use `addslashes()`, but then I realized it didn't solve many security issues, so I added `htmlspecialchars()`, and now I have this line of code:

```
$val=htmlspecialchars(addslashes(trim($val)));
```

But then I was wondering if it makes any sense at all to use `addslashes()` on a string that will be processed by `htmlspecialchars()`, since the latter will "remove" any element that would cause problems, if I'm not mistaken.

In particular, I was wondering if that makes the server work twice without any real need.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (What you need to know to work with text within text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism)

Comment: Would also be the incorrect order. If you were to escape HTML, then do that prior database escaping (m_r_e_s). -- Or learn about [`PDO and prepared statements`](http://www.google.com/search?q=PDO%20and%20prepared%20statements), as that's less cumbersome regarding DB handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use either of those when saving the string to the database.

- `addslashes()` escapes only quote characters and the backslash character (\).  It's not adequate for avoiding SQL injection, because the DBMS may use other special characters which would have to be escaped as well.  The best way to avoid SQL injection is to use [PHP data objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and its support for bind parameters, which let you keep the parameter values out of the SQL string entirely.  If PDO isn't an option for some reason, you should at least use a database-specific escaping function, e.g. [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) if you're using MySQL, to ensure that all the necessary characters are escaped.
- `htmlspecialchars()` is for use when incorporating a non-HTML string into an HTML page; it escapes characters that are significant to a web browser, such as angle brackets, and has nothing to do with databases.  Assuming that you're not generating and storing complete HTML documents in your database, you shouldn't be calling this function on values before putting them into the database.  Store what the user actually entered, and call `htmlspecialchars()` when you retrieve the value *from* the database and you're about to actually put it into some HTML output.

Comment: addslashes() is NOT meant to avoid SQL injection, it only looks like it's doing it. It might miss a bunch of more exotic characters depending on parameters like used encoding and stuff like that.

Comment: It's *meant* to avoid SQL injection, it's just not a *good* way to avoid SQL injection.  (A database-specific escaping function like `mysql_real_escape_string()` is better, but of course PDO bind parameters are even better.)

Answer (score 9):

You are wrong alltogether. `addslashes()` is no database escaping function, use the one that comes with your database access extension, like `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

`htmlspecialchars()` completey does not makes sense here. Only use it if you want to place a string within HTML - that should be when you output stuff, not when storing it in the database.